# What does 出马 mean in the below sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure

这是我在做的一个课本练习：

> 用指定词语改述下列句子：
>
> 你还别不相信，他一到谁知道什么毛病。【出马】

我不知道这里怎么能用【出马】。下面这个句子是对的吗？

> 如果你不出马，他一到谁知道什么毛病。

而且我对这个部分不太理解：【你还别不相信】 是什么意思？【别+不】这个结合我不懂。

谢谢！

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not useful to those who can't fluently read Chinese

Answer (score 3, accepted):

正确答案应该是:

> 你还别不相信，他出马准知道什么毛病。

or

> 你还别不相信，他一出马准知道什么毛病。

出马: take up the matter

你还别不相信: you should believe.

"别不"是双重否定，表示肯定。

Comment: Is it reasonable to read "不相信" as a set phrase meaning "doubt?"  Because those words commonly go together,  it is natural to write the double negative "别不相信" for "don't doubt."

Comment: 不相信 = disbelieve;  懷疑 = doubt. The  two are different.

Comment: Perhaps the double negative 别不相信 could be translated as "do not not believe"?